# Reading a file in prolog

Tags: io, prolog, dcg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read a file line by line in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805601/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-prolog)

I found the following prolog code which reads one character at a time and prints out.

```
process(File) :-
        open('C:/Users/BHARAT/Desktop/a.txt', read, In),
        get_char(In, Char1),
        process_stream(Char1, In),
        close(In).

process_stream(end_of_file, _) :- !.
process_stream(Char, In) :-
        print(Char),
        get_char(In, Char2),
        process_stream(Char2, In).
```

But if the file has multiple lines is there a way to read 1 whole line at a time so that it will be easy for tokenizing.

Answer (score 5):

You say you want to tokenize the input - the best way to do this are definite clause grammars (DCGs). With `library(pio)` in SWI you can use the grammar directly to read in a file like so:

```
?- use_module(library(pio)).
?- phrase_from_file(seq(Xs),f).

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).
```

Replace now `seq//1` by some more elaborate tokenizer.

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has some support predicate, for instance:

```
..., read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes), phrase(parse, Codes, []), ...
```

But I would advise you to adopt phrase_from_file/2 (as already suggested in another answer). There is a support library to help parsing input, with some ready to use parser:

```
:- use_module(library(http/dcg_basics)).
```

**edit** the support library has been renamed, there is a back compatibility trick, that allows old naming, but now it's better to use library([dcg/basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl)).