# Read a file line by line error in prolog

Tags: prolog, readfile, swi-prolog

For reading a file i'm using below code, but this code reads only lines where there is a '.' in the end of file, is there another way to read any kind of file and store in the list?

```
main :-
   open('myFile.txt', read, Str),
   read_file(Str,Lines),
   close(Str),
   write(Lines), nl.

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream).
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read(Stream,X),
    read_file(Stream,L).
```

I took this code from this link
[Read a file line by line in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805601/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-prolog)

Comment: See this answer for a summary of options for reading a file (line by line or otherwise) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005369/read-from-a-file-or-stream

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the code you wrote is inherently incorrect for the following reasons.

1mo, you are reading Prolog data, and not lines at all. Take `a. b. c.` which would make a list `[a,b,c]`.

2do, testing for `at_end_of_stream/1` is extremely tricky, and does not work as expected when reading Prolog data. Take the 3-line file:

```
first_fact.
second_fact.
% no comment - oh that's a comment nevertheless
```

This will give you the list `[first_fact, second_fact, end_of_file]`. For `read/1` gives you a term `end_of_file` after having read the last line.

3tio, upon backtracking, `main` will always produce an error!

```
?- main.
[first_fact,second_fact,end_of_file]
true ;
ERROR: at_end_of_stream/1: stream `<stream>(0x1c38330)' does not exist
```

If you want to read just bytes use [`library(pio)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[prolog]+%22library%28pio%29%22). And to use that, first learn the [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) formalism.
The following will succeed for each occurrence of `magic` in the file:

```
?- phrase_from_file((..., "magic", ...), filename).
```

using the following definition of `... //0`:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

See [this for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805709/772868).

Comment: I'm very beginner at prolog, I just simple read data a from a file and write or do something else line by line. I checked the phrase_from_file and pio library usage, they seem not fit my example. basicly i want to do this

list=readAllLines()
foreach(line in lines)
  if do_something(line) ==true
  count++

Comment: @seleucia: The link at the end of my answer describes exactly this case. Doing general I/O in Prolog as a beginner is otherwise not a good idea. First learn the language without general I/O.

Comment: I used the link you send me, but it is generating, not my list something i don't know
  <br/>
for example my data.txt have this data
  <br/>
12
  <br/>
34
  <br/>
56
  <br/>

and it is pringting something else
  <br/>
  59
  <br/>
  99

Comment: @seleucia: To process such kind of data, you will need to learn [tag:dcg] first. There is no way around!

Comment: I don't understand your comment, i need only read file and put it in a list, this very simple operation in any other language. I'm doing this for my homework.

Comment: I have to iterate with in this data and count how many of them fits with dcg. For example i want to check the line if it is a date or not.

Comment: @seleucia: So you need to write a DCG first.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, it help  me to solve the problem.