# How to count the number of words in a file in Prolog

Tags: prolog

In a multi-line text file, determine the number of words in
each line and enter information about this in a separate line of the new file in the form:
line #  contains  words.The file contains only words, for example "Marry Christmas" is 2 words.

Comment: This can be very easy (see the comment under the answer by @Deffa) or maybe not. How do you define a word? Do you need to count how many times each word appears in the file? Also, please show some attempt at solving it. Downvoting until this question is possible to answer. (You can edit your question with more details and code.)

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how to do this yet. According to the assignment, you need to count the number of words in a line of the file and display this number

Comment: If you want useful help you need to do two things. 1. Understand the problem statement and transmit it faithfully. 2. At least attempt something on your own. And beware, the only answer you've got so far has bugs in it, see my comments.

Comment: Thank you, I will write you a full assignment, maybe you can help me. In a multi-line text file, determine the number of words in
each line and enter information about this in a separate line of the new file in the form:
line # <line number> contains <number of words per line> words

Comment: So you need to create a new file, with exactly as many lines as the original? How about the definition of "word". How many words we have here: `a b:c`? How about here: `a+b = c`? And please update your question, do not add details in the comments

Comment: You need to be able to define what makes a word. Are they just separated by white space?

Comment: Yes, the words are just separated by a space. That is, for example, in our file there are several lines, on each line there is a set of words. You need to output information about each line to a new file, for example: line 1 contains 5 words\n
line 2 contains 1 word

Comment: By "a space" or by any number of spaces?

Comment: Normal space, it's only one between words

Comment: The file looks like this: line 1: It snowed today (4 words), line 2: I woke up at 12 o'clock (6 words)

Comment: so if you have two consecutive white spaces you will have a 0-length word between the two spaces that you need to count?

Comment: No, it is assumed that there cannot be more than 1 consecutive space.

Comment: so should the program break if t here more than one space? Or should it just take multiple spaces as one?

Comment: Use multiple spaces as one or you can just display a warning that there are many spaces and exit the program, it seems to me that it will be easier to write code

Comment: How are you going to read the file? Line by line, writing to the other file?

Comment: To be honest, I tried to read from a file, but it did not work for me, I have never programmed in functional languages, can you show the code how to at least approximately complete my task?

Comment: Did you see the answer you got already? There is some link there. But it also depends on what predicates you are supposed to be using for this, it depends on your learning materials.

Answer (score -1):

You can see this answer on how to read a file: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805931/14134202)
Once the lines are read, counting is pretty straight forward. Iterate over all lines and split them with  [split_string/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=split_string/4):

```
lines(["word1 word2", "word3 word4"]).

word_count(C):- lines(LS), %read file here instead
    count(LS, C).
count([], 0).
count([L|LS], C) :- split_string(L, " ", "", W), 
    length(W, N1), count(LS, N2), C is N1 + N2.
```

Comment: At that point you could just read the whole file to a string, split it, then use length. Why the recursion? Like this: `read_string(Input, _, S), split_string(S, "\s\t\n", "\s\t\n", W), length(W, N).`

Comment: What will happen if you have several white spaces after each other? Try: `split_string("a      b", " ", "", W).`