# Why is Prolog being a jerk

Tags: prolog

`sorted.csv`

```
01Vbe,2r5/3Qnk1p/8/4B2b/Pp2p3/1P2P3/5PPP/3R2K1 w - - 3 32,d1d6 c8c1 d6d1 c1d1 d7d1 h5d1,600,80,100,63
3,advantage endgame fork long,https://lichess.org/b334W1Ga#63
01GC2,3b4/pp2kprp/8/1Bp5/4R3/1P6/P4PPP/1K6 b - - 0 22,e7f8 e4e8,600,82,89,374,endgame mate mateIn1 on
eMove,https://lichess.org/6c75Zk3T/black#44
```

`file_line` reads the code line by line as posted in this answer:
[Read a file line by line in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805601/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-prolog/69006410#69006410)

```
stuff(Lines) :- findall(Tags,
  (
    file_line("data/athousand_sorted.csv", Line),
    csv_fen(Line, Fen, Moves, Id, Tags),
    maplist(atom_string, TagsAtom, Tags),
    tags_with(TagsAtom, mateIn1)
  ),
  Lines).

csv_fen(Line, Fen, Moves, Id, Tags) :- split_string(Line, ",", "", [Id, Fen, Moves, _, _, _, _, Tags|
_]).

tags_with(Tags, Tag) :- split_string(Tags, " ", "", Ls), member(Tag, Ls).
```

maplist(atom_string, XYZ), doesn't work for string read from a file,
though this works on the repl.

`?- maplist(atom_string, Tags, ["mateIn1"]).`

I want to filter lines of this file that has `mateIn1` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you a hint? (Is `Tags` a list of strings?)

```
?- csv_fen("id,fen,move,b1,b2,b3,b4,tags", Fen, Moves, Id, Tags).
Fen = "fen",
Moves = "move",
Id = "id",
Tags = "tags".
```

Comment: `maplist(atom_string, TagsAtom, Tags),` there is this line which turns Tags into atoms into `TagsAtom`. Btw, I also tested with string version like `tags_with(TagsAtom, "mateIn1")` that also didn't work.

Comment: The definition for maplist is: maplist(Predicate, List1, List2). Your `Tags` is not a list - it's a string. Query `maplist(atom_string, TagsAtom, ["matIn1"])` produces `TagsAtom = [matIn1]`; query `maplist(atom_string, TagsAtom, "matIn1")` fails because `"matin1"` doesn't unify with a list.

Comment: Wow, that worked, I added this 
`tags_with(Tags, Tag) :- split_string(Tags, " ", "", Ls), maplist(atom_string, Atoms, Ls), member(Tag, Atoms).` . 
Thanks